# Replace missing values

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

```
M     Price Quantity    Quantity1
---------------------------------
2014m1  55  150          150
2014m2  55  220          220
2014m3  55  350          87,5
2014m4  55  NA           87,5
2014m5  55  NA           87,5
2014m6  55  NA           87,5
2014m8  58  200           200
```

This is sample of my table. Namely I want get result like Quantity1. This means if some value is NA, code should divide by numbers of NA plus 1.

E.g 350 should be replace with 87,5(=350/4) and also next three values should replace with 87,5.

So can anybody help me with this code with loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Base R, we can use `ave`:

```
df$Quantity1 = ave(df$Quantity, cumsum(!is.na(df$Quantity)), 
                   FUN = function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE)/length(x))
```

Also, with `data.table` (credits to @Jaap):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, Quantity1 := max(Quantity, na.rm = TRUE)/.N, by = cumsum(!is.na(Quantity))]
```

**Output:**

```
       M Price Quantity Quantity1
1 2014m1    55      150     150.0
2 2014m2    55      220     220.0
3 2014m3    55      350      87.5
4 2014m4    55       NA      87.5
5 2014m5    55       NA      87.5
6 2014m6    55       NA      87.5
7 2014m8    58      200     200.0
```

or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(na_id = cumsum(!is.na(Quantity))) %>%
  mutate(Quantity1 = max(Quantity, na.rm = TRUE)/n())
```

Note: we can add `ungroup() %>% select(-na_id)` to remove `na_id` column.

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   na_id [4]
  M      Price Quantity na_id Quantity1
  <fct>  <int>    <int> <int>     <dbl>
1 2014m1    55      150     1     150  
2 2014m2    55      220     2     220  
3 2014m3    55      350     3      87.5
4 2014m4    55       NA     3      87.5
5 2014m5    55       NA     3      87.5
6 2014m6    55       NA     3      87.5
7 2014m8    58      200     4     200
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(M = structure(1:7, .Label = c("2014m1", "2014m2", 
"2014m3", "2014m4", "2014m5", "2014m6", "2014m8"), class = "factor"), 
    Price = c(55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 58L), Quantity = c(150L, 
    220L, 350L, NA, NA, NA, 200L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), .Names = c("M", "Price", "Quantity"))
```

Comment: Implemented in `data.table`; `setDT(df)[, Quantity1 := max(Quantity, na.rm = TRUE)/.N, by = cumsum(!is.na(Quantity))]`

Comment: @Jaap Great, let me add that to the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think, the below code works for you:

```
getValueindices<-function(dt){which( is.na(dt))-1  } #find replace candidate


setValue<-function(indices,dt ){            # replace Na with previous value
  for(i in indices)
    if(min(indices)==i)
      dt[i+1]<-dt[i]/(sum(is.na(dt))+1)
    else
      dt[i+1]<-dt[i]
  dt
} 

getValueindices(df$Quantity)
setValue(indices,df$Quantity)

df$Quantity1<- setValue(indices,df$Quantity)

df
```

and the output is:

```
       M Price Quantity Quantity1
1 2014m1    55      150     150.0
2 2014m2    55      220     220.0
3 2014m3    55      350     350.0
4 2014m4    55       NA      87.5
5 2014m5    55       NA      87.5
6 2014m6    55       NA      87.5
7 2014m8    58      200     200.0
```